# How to create a "guided tour" in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for ideas, best practices, gems (if such exist) that would allow me to easily create a guided tour for an existing Rails 4 web application.

I would like any new user that signs up to be greeted with a welcome message that explains some of the site's features. When they click "Next", they should go to another page (say, projects list) where another explanatory message appears. Next step would be yet another page (e.g. tasks list) with message and so on... I'd like the explanatory messages to be as unobtrusive as possible, similar to flash messages.

The possibility to skip or hide the guided tour and start it over later would be, of course, very nice to have.

I know that I could create it "by hand" using cookies and some additional controller logic (flash messages) but wouldn't like to pollute all of the controllers with additional logic for guided tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is IntroJs http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/, both this and Baldrick's answer are great options.

Comment: I went with this one, but both options seem nice and easy.

Comment: For people looking at this now, intro.js is no more maintained so Shepherd (as said by jabbet in his answer) might be a better solution. And it's free unlike intro.js.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using [Shepherd.js](https://shepherdjs.dev/docs/) for the last several months in my Rails apps. I found it handles itself best of all the JavaScript tour libraries in a responsive webapp, as the mobile experience is an important part of our product. Plus, its provided themes were easy to integrate into our existing look-and-feel. (You can install the [Shepherd.js rails-assets gem](https://rails-assets.org/#/components/shepherd.js) for easier use in the asset pipeline.)

I've since wrapped Shepherd.js into a Rails gem called [Abraham](https://github.com/actmd/abraham) to make it easier to configure tour content, track which users have seen each tour, and allow users to skip a tour for now.

Comment: Can Abraham be used with rails 6? And how is it installed, still over the Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery plugin [Joyride](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) for this.

I would create a controller dedicated to the guided tour that renders some of your existing views (for example  '/tour/1', '/tour/2', 'tour/3', ...), but add inside the hidden html `ol` used by Joyride (see the doc). At the end of the tour on each page, use the Joyride callback `postRideCallback` to redirect user to the next page of the tour.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was looking rather for a Rails-based, since my site is not a Single Page App, but maybe I will give it a try. I think I could create a separate quick tour for each of the main pages of the app. As for your other idea (the tour controller), I don't really like it, sorry! I feel reusing the views in this way would be hard to maintain...